# Embed Excel spreadsheet inside PDF

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf

Is it possible to embed an Excel spreadsheet in a PDF file that updates automatically whenever you open the PDF (like Word does)? I want to show the spreadsheet contents (with updates) in the PDF. I want new updates to show in the PDF without having to open the Excel spreadsheet itself.

Comment: Very good question. As pdf's are normally only used to hold static information (information that does not change) I would guess the answer is no, you would need to re-create the pdf each time you change the excel data.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I figured this was the case, but it never hurts to probe.

Answer (score 0):

As Kevin suggests, PDF is for retaining the formatting that you started with. If you don't want it to be stable pick a different delivery tool.

Reference
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/save-as-pdf-HA010064992.aspx