# I saw a pdf which held a small (blank) excel table which had a cross in the corner. It seemed to be embedded in the pdf

Tags: pdf, microsoft-excel-2016

When clicked it opened up the excel table in the pdf. How do you do that?

Comment: @aa2397 lmgtfy comments are considered rude. Please do not post them. If you have an answer, if you have a *constructive* comment to help OP to improve their question then post that. "Lmgtfy" is not constructive.

Answer (score 0):

PDF is for retaining the formatting that you started with. This need seems to require some additional tools.

Acrobat 8 (and thus, subsequent versions) include the ability to package files of different types within a pdf file:

https://helpx.adobe.com/reader/archive.html?content=WSE034CA46-D08F-4fff-AA3C-FF04510DAEF0.html

This issue seems to have been discussed, so you can look at this similar situation below:

[Embed Excel spreadsheet inside PDF](https://superuser.com/questions/544127/embed-excel-spreadsheet-inside-pdf)